# Can I save myself the image from camera intent?

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing an application that takes a picture from camera and encrypt it.
My idea is to use the camera intent and then get image to encrypt.

The problem is that I want to get the image generated by camera and encrypt it **before** is written to SDCARD.

I've read the tutorials and all of them uses the "put_extra" function to set the filename for save the picture.

It's possible to get the JPG in RAM and not to save it in SD? Or in this case is mandatory to make my own camera?

I know I can let the camera to write the image, encrypt it and then remove the old one, but isn't safe, because someone can try to recover deleted files from SD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what you have try ?

Comment: i don't think you can get the full-size image (only a preview subsampled version of it)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't do that without saving to file.
However consider to create your own camera activity, then you will have much more control over the camera. Use surface view for the camera preview, and implement your custom PictureCallback and override the onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) so you can get the image data without saving it to the filesystem.

Comment: All of you are right. The camera intent just allow you to specify the external file where you want to save the image (using extra_data). 
Thank you in any case.